# Modify CSS to hide

Tags: css, sharepoint, toolbar

I need to hide the "Actions" menu from a document library's toolbar. I know in CSS I can use this "`{display: none}`" syntax to hide.

Can someone please help find me the right place where I need to put this? I found this .ms-actionbar but dont know if this guy belong to list toolbar or site toolbar.

For example:  http://www.xsolive.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: can you show the HTML produced?

Comment: Can you give as a live example?

Comment: @Bob you are asking a generic solution for a specific problem, the code would be needed to provide a good answer. thanks!

Comment: Go to any document library of the sharepoint and you will see "New" "Upload" "Actions" and "Settings" in the toolbar of the list.

Comment: @Bob Dinero, you really need to link us to your live site or an example of HTML/source code you can give us. Telling us to look at any document library of the sharepoint literally could mean anything.

Comment: It's a internal site. but look at this link to get a feel for what I am talking about.  http://www.xsolive.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CSS rule will hide the elements from your toolbar :

```
.ms-menutoolbar td 
{
    display:none;
}
```

Note that this will hide all the menus from your toolbar though. If there are other buttons you want to show in the toolbar you'll have to modify it though. Using the id of that particular button will work.

For the URL you provided, the rule would be :

```
#zz8_ListActionsMenu_t 
{
    display:none;
}
```

For your question :

Not with css you can't. The "Actions" menu is generated dynamically by SharePoint and it's ID won't always be the same.
You can do it with javascript though.

Here is how you would do it with jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var link = $('a[id$="ListActionsMenu"]').filter(':contains("Actions")');
    link.parent().hide();
});
```

A very simplified version of the HTML code looks like this for the menu :

```
<div id="zz8_ListActionsMenu_t">
    <a id="zz8_ListActionsMenu">Actions</a>
</div>
```

What the jQuery code does is that it first finds all the `<a>` with an ID that ends with ListActionsMenu (which should limit the selection to the content of the toolbar) and then finds the one with the text "Action".
It then removes the whole div.

Comment: I noticed that the first part "zz8" is different in dev , test and prod. In dev it's zz23, Test is zz25, Prod is zz14.. Now what? Is there a way to automatically read the zz part plus ListActionsMenu_t?

Comment: It worked with jQuery method. I put it in the master page. Thanks Hugo

Answer (score 3):

I always go with experimentation. Just start hiding stuff.

Also if you use chrome, open up the page in question, right click on the element, and select "Inspect element" this will show you it's id/classes etc.

There are similar tools in FF, but I don't really use FF except for testing.

Comment: Let me try FF cause I dont have chrome installed on my dev.

Comment: You should switch to FF, it follows the spec the most closely and Firebug is by far the best tool out there for developers!

Comment: @Kyle - Chrome has built in dev tools (press Ctrl+ Shift + J). There is also a firebug plugin for Chrome (http://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/chrome/)

Comment: When did firebug come out for chrome? I thought I was watching that closely, thanks Matt! (I knew already about Chromes developer tools, I just think Firebug is TONS better)

Comment: @Kyle: I have FF installed, but for most of my browsing, I use chrome, to me it's personal preference. I certainly don't disparage FF users, but I'm a bit of a Google fanboy.

Comment: I use Chrome as my main browser, I forgot to mention that, but firebugs tools are superior :) I've just been using Chrome's tools, cuz I have no FF here, and was wishing for Firebug!

Comment: The element is zz8_ListActionsMenu" .  ALL I AM HEARING HOW TO USE A CLIENT (LIKE FF OR CHROME). I NEED A SOLUTION HERE GUYS. I KNOW ALL OF THAT SO FAR HAVE BEEN SUGGESTED. IT'S TIME FOR SOME ACTION. LOL

Answer (score 2):

use fire bug in FF to get the CSS class name by doing inspect element