# Javascript to hide buttons in a Sharepoint Document List

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I've followed/modified the directions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315016/modify-css-to-hide/5160294#5160294) to hide the "UPLOAD" button on a Sharepoint 2007 list.  The issue I'm encountering is that the dropdown arrow for the Upload menu still appears.  How can I get rid of the whole menu item?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Take a look at http://features.codeplex.com/. It has Toolbar Manager

This Feature allows you to selectively show and hide menu items on the standard list/library toolbar.

Hide the `zz17_UploadMenu_t` table.

If you understood the answer in the question you linked, you wouldn't be asking this question. :-)

Use tools like firebug/Developer Tools (IE) to find solutions for these kind of issues.

Comment: I did understand the answer and followed it to the letter, but am still experiencing an issue.  Instead of criticism, steps to help me diagnose the issue are more welcome.  Two of the issues are that a) I don't have access to the CSS and b) the ID changes each time.

Comment: Sorry! I wouldn't have added that "criticism" if you had told that you tried what I said :-)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  And no hard feelings